# Hook Trait into each Eloquent Select Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've made a small Trait for filtering an `Eloquent` Query. Now I want to apply this function in the Trait to each `SELECT` query before returning instead of calling
`$data = MyModel::all()->filterable()`,
`$data = MyModel::with('foo')->filterable()`
etc each time. Is this actually possible?

For example, [the nullable package](https://github.com/deringer/laravel-nullable-fields/blob/master/src/NullableFields.php#L25) does it by observing
via `static::saving(function ($model) { ...`
Can this be done for selecting data, too?

Comment: i think your looking for query scopes. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I'm using a query scope right now, but it has to be applied to each query manually. I was asking if this could be automated. So when I'm calling `Model::all()` it runs the usual all() function and applied my function afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Global Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes).